# How to get the parent element id from multiple droppables with same class?

Tags: jquery, droppable

I have a folder tree structure ...code for 1 block is as below:

```
<div level="1" class="tree-item " ispublic="false" hassubfold="true" isworkspace="0" foldid="3595517$$QC4ixP" dcid="1" proid="54445$$vnwCUD" id="fold_3595517$$QC4ixP">
    <div style="padding-left: 30px; float: none; width: auto;" class="tree-row   ui-droppable selected">
            <span class="openFolder"></span>
        <span class="tree-label">1001</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tree-children" style="display: block;">
        <div>
        <div level="2" class="tree-item " ispublic="false" hassubfold="false" isworkspace="0" foldid="3711515$$AhXpf3" dcid="1" proid="54445$$vnwCUD" id="fold_3711515$$AhXpf3">
        <div style="padding-left: 50px; float: none; width: auto;" class="tree-row  ui-droppable">
        <a style="visibility:hidden;width:20px;" rel="undefined" title="Expand" class="folder" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
        <a rel="54445$$vnwCUD" class="docList ui-droppable" title="rrrr" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="closeFolder "></span>
        <span class="tree-label">rrrr</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tree-children"></div>
</div>
```

I need to drag the file from list having checkbox and drop in .tree-row(folder tree). When it drops d file i need to get the foldid of tree-item which i get thru below code:

```
event.target.parentElement.attributes['id'].value
```

Using above, i get multiple foldid of div containing .tree-item.  I need to get the folder id only of the folder on which file is dropped which is sub folder again....

```
function bindDragDropDocEvent(){    
    $(".tree-row").droppable({
        accept: '#fileContent .rows',
         tolerance: "touch", 

        drop:function(event,ui){
            event.stopPropagation();
            console.log(event);
            alert("dropped");
            var foldid = event.target.parentElement.attributes['foldid'].value;
            if(foldid!=0){
               foldid = event.target.parentElement.attributes['foldid'].value;  
               alert(foldid);
            }
         },
});

$("#fileContent .rows").draggable({
        cursor:'move',
        stop:function(event,ui){
            event.stopPropagation();
            var rowdata = ui.helper.find(':checkbox').data('rowValues');
            alert(rowdata.fileName);
         },
    });
}
```

Can anyone pls help on this to get the droppable folder ID only and not its parent. I have used greedy:true but no luck !.

Comment: you should try console.logging $(this) around where your declaring foldid. you're using jquery anyway.. Please make a JSFiddle for better help

Answer (score 0):

I think your draggable touchs multiple divs when you drop it, thats why you get parent div's id as well.
possible solutions:

- remove `tolerance: "touch",`
- increase padding on `.tree-row`